# transform.scale() not working on new objects

Tags: python, pygame

So im trying to do a slime animation for multiple objects on screen, with one object everything works perfectly, when i add another object somehow some of the the images get transformed back to their original size for both objects, even though everything worked perfectly at the start with one object. The class constructor:

```
   def __init__(self,image=[],rate=ra.randint(1,6),anim=0,mov=0):
    self.mov=mov
    self.img=image
    self.rate=rate
    self.anim=anim
    for i in range(1,9):
        self.img+=[pygame.image.load("../graphics/enemies/slimes/slime_blue/slime_blue"+str(i)+".png")] #im adding every image in a list for each object here
        self.img[i-1]=pygame.transform.scale(self.img[i-1],(dis[0]/25,dis[0]/25)) #im adjusting every image to the size i want
    Enemy.__init__(self,rarity=ra.random(),strength=ra.randint(2,19),defence=ra.randint(0,10),life=ra.randint(20,50),speed=ra.randint(1,10))
```

the process of adding new objects:

```
if ra.randint(1,50)==1:
        slimes+=[Slime()]
```

the animation process:

```
def animate(self,pos):      
        box_slime=screen.blit(self.img[self.anim],pos)
        if self.anim<len(self.img) -1 :
            self.anim+=1
        else:
            self.anim=0
        return box_slime
```

Comment: *"somehow some of the the images get transformed back to their original size"* - No, definitely not. You messed up something elsewhere in your code.

Comment: thats what i thought but i haven't done any image transforming outside the class( for the slime images at least )

Comment: Possible "mutable default argument" problem here, due to `image=[]` in the parameter list - every instance of this class that doesn't get a specified value for that parameter will end up sharing the same `self.img` list.

Answer (score 0):

this fixed it, im not really sure why but yeah.

```
for i in range(1,9):
    img=pygame.image.load("../graphics/enemies/slimes/slime_blue/slime_blue"+str(i)+".png")
    img=pygame.transform.scale(img,(dis[0]/25,dis[0]/25))
    self.img.append(img)
```